# Pythonを用いてsalesforceのchatterにコメントを投稿したい

Tags: python

手始めにpythonからsalesforceのRestApiを用いて、chatterにコメントを投稿できるようにしたいです。
公式のドキュメントを参考にしたのですが、何かが間違っているみたいです。
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.ja-jp.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/quickreference_post_comment_to_feed_element.htm

現状抱えている問題として、以下のエラーコードが返ってきてしまいます。

```
'[{"errorCode":"NOT_FOUND","message":"The requested resource does not exist"}]'
```

pythonとRESTApiを使い始めて1か月ぐらいです。よろしくお願いします

```
import requests
import json
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
import base64
import requests

# 設定ファイルOPE
json_file = open('config.json', 'r')
json_data = json.load(json_file)

# ログインに必要な情報を取得
URL_AUTH = json_data["SF_URL"]
GRANT_TYPE = json_data["GRANT_TYPE"]
CLIENT_ID = json_data["CLIENT_ID"]
CLIENT_SECRET = json_data["CLIENT_SECRET"]
USERNAME = json_data["SF_LOGIN_USERNAME"]
PASSWORD = json_data["SFDC_LOGIN_PASSWORD"]

# ログイン情報を格納 OAuth2.0認証
data = {
    "grant_type": "password",
    "client_id": CLIENT_ID,
    "client_secret": CLIENT_SECRET,
    "username": USERNAME,
    "password": PASSWORD + [ここは個別トークンです
}

# headerを設定
headers = {
    'content-type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}
res = requests.post(URL_AUTH, data=data, headers=headers)

# 実行結果の取得
session=requests.Session()
res_info=json.loads(res.text)
instance_url=res_info['instance_url']
access_token=res_info['access_token']

# salesforceオブジェクトの生成
sf = Salesforce(
    instance_url=instance_url
    ,session_id=access_token
    ,session=session
)

# パラメータの作成
parm = {
    "messageSegments" : {
            "type" : "Text",
            "text" : "New comment"
    }
}

# headers
headers = {
    "Authorization" : "Bearer " + access_token
}

response = requests.post(instance_url +"/services/data/v52.0/chatter/feed-elements/feedElementId/capabilities/comments/items", data=parm, headers=headers)
response.text
```

Comment: こんな記事 [class SalesforcePy.chatter.ChatterFeedComment(session_id, instance_url, _id, body, **kwargs)](https://salesforcepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/SalesforcePy.html?SalesforcePy.chatter.ChatterFeedComment#SalesforcePy.chatter.ChatterFeedComment) の説明から推測すると、`feedElementId`というのはその文字列そのものでは無く、対象のリソースに割り当てられた`id`を指定しなければいけないのでは？ だからコメントするためには、その対象となるリソースの`id`を何とかして取得する必要があると思われます。

Comment: @kunif コメントありがとうございます。
ご指摘いただいた様に、Idを指定する必要があるようでした。。
feedElementIdの取得方法なども含めて今調査をしているところです。
とりあえず沼から片足出た感じがします。。もう少し頑張ってみます。